# What supporting evidence is required for a Moroccan travel visa?

Tags: visas, uk, hostels, morocco

I plan to travel to Morocco later this year and wanted to check if anyone with previous experience getting a travel visa can shed some light here. [The Embassy of Morocco in the UK](http://www.moroccanembassylondon.org.uk/en/viisa.html) states that for a travel visa, the following documents are required (among others):

> - Copy of your detailed **provisional** flight itinerary.
> - Hotel **provisional**    reservation or notarized Letter of Invitation
>     from your sponsor in    Morocco.

However, [Visa Guru](http://www.visaguru.co.uk/182/223/India/Morocco/visa-requirements.htm)...

> Copy or Original hotel confirmation (Hotel confirmation must show
>   **paid in full**.)

...and [Visa HQ](http://morocco.visahq.co.uk/requirements/India/resident-United_Kingdom/)...

> Copy of **confirmed** hotel reservations **issued directly from the hotel**.

...seem to imply stricter restrictions on what is an acceptable form of accommodation proof. So my questions are:

1. Is a booking done through a third-party site (Hostelworld, Expedia, the lot) acceptable?
2. Does the accommodation booking *have* to be paid for in full? (Because with some booking websites, only a deposit is taken.)
3. Is a hostel booking (rather than a hotel booking) - either paid partly or in full - even considered as a valid supporting document for a Moroccan travel visa?

Comment: Maybe add your home country to the question. For Dutch citizens, for example, you can just get your passport stamped on the spot, no extra requirements whatsoever.

Comment: Correct, I hold an Indian passport. This question is specifically for those not covered under via-free/on-arrival.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to call up the Moroccan Embassy in London for a few weeks but they never attend to phone calls! I consulted with a visa service agency based in the UK called [CIBT](http://uk.cibt.com) and here's what they told me (since this is not an official response, your mileage may vary):

- Your hotel reservation **does not** need to show payment has been made in full. All it needs to show is that the booking has been made for the period you plan to stay in Morocco.
- Bookings made through any online travel agencies such as Expedia, Travelocity, et al are allowed. I'm not sure whether this covers Hostelworld too but I don't fundamentally see why it should make a difference, unless they are biased against hostel bookings.

I got my visa without any issues, without having to splurge on making fully-paid hotel bookings.

Comment: @pnuts I did get it in the end! Updated answer accordingly.