# Is it difficult for an Iranian citizen to get a visa to travel to Morocco as a tourist?

Tags: visas, morocco, iranian-citizens

Where I am now in Georgia there is a backpacker from Iran who would like to travel to Morocco but thinks it is not possible for Iranian citizens since the countries do not have embassies in each other's territory.

But is this true? I expect it's not easy to look up on the Internet since most information will be in Arabic and/or Persian.

What must he do to obtain a visa etc?

Comment: I am in ankara turkey now ..i wnt to the embassy of morroco here..they said iranians should apply for visa from jordon..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to @mouviciel's answer, yes, Morocco and Iran do have an embassy presence in each others countries but here's the catch: you can only apply for a Moroccan visa in a country you aren't a citizen of *only* if you're a resident of that country. So in this case, your Iranian friend would need to be resident in Georgia to be able to apply for a visa in the embassy there; otherwise, he needs to apply for a Moroccan visa back in Iran.

I found this out when doing research for [my own Moroccan visa issues](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2181/supporting-evidence-required-for-moroccan-travel-visa).

Comment: Oh no so he has the same problem I have with a Russian visa! I'll let him know tomorrow - thanks.

Comment: FYI, as of now, Iran and Morocco have no embassies any more. They had problems and closed the embassies.

Answer (score 8):

[worldembassyinformation.com](http://www.worldembassyinformation.com/embassy-of-morocco/iran.html) has a different opinion:

#### Embassy of Morocco in Tehran, Tehran, Islamic Republic of Iran

Street Address: Av Lavassani- Vatanpour-Shahid, Davoud Barati NÂ°5

Phone: (+98-21) 22206731, 22206732

Fax: (+98-21) 22210169

Email: sifamateh@ocean-net.com

#### Embassy of Iran in Rabat, Rabat, Kingdom of Morocco

Street Address: Route De Zair, Route Bir Kacem Suissi

Postal Address: PO Box 490

Phone: (+212-3) 7750353, 7659121, 7752167

Fax: (+212-3) 7659118

Comment: Bah well that seems pretty easy after all. Maybe he meant there's no Moroccan embassy here in Tbilisi but we can deal with that I think. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: My friend thinks there was some kind of change with the Moroccan embassy/ambassador in Tehran recently that makes it not possible to get a visa at the moment. But I gave him the links so he can chase down more details.