# How to apply for a Moroccan visa from Tehran?

Tags: visas, morocco

I would like to apply a visa for travel to Morocco from Tehran.

How can I make an application?

Comment: You find the [embassy of Iran in Rabat](https://embassy-finder.com/iran_in_rabat_morocco) with the given address. You contact them and ask if you need a visa and if yes, to send the application to you.

Comment: Do you have an Iranian passport?

Answer (score 5):

At risk of sounding a bit obvious, Google's first two entries should be the Moroccan consulate in your country, and [www.moroccanconsulate.com/Visa_new_form.pdf](http://www.moroccanconsulate.com/Visa_new_form.pdf)

You should definitely read the associated pages on the Moroccan consulate as regards requirements and restrictions - this will be important. We also have a range of questions here (look in the Related sidebar to the right) especially [this one on supporting evidence](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2181/1381).

Comment: AFAIK, no more relation between Morocco and Iran... or was it back?

Comment: certainly not as good a relationship as it was, no